# Does "pour forth" mean large amount or small amount?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

I just found three definitions of "pour forth" from [this site](https://wordnerd.fun/pour%20forth), which are as follows:

> 1. to appear in large numbers

> 2. to be uttered, especially in a long flow of speech

> 3. pour out in drops or small quantities or as if in drops or small quantities verb

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pour%20forth) only has the third definition.

What I don't understand is that the first two definitions imply large amount, but the third definition says small quantities. Don't they contradict to each other?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say because I don't recognize the third meaning.  Even with water, I would expect something "poured forth" would be a continuous flow, though it might be a small one.

Comment: Pour relates to the rams fee or flow of fluid (or things, or thoughts etc) from one place to another. Water pours from a spoon to a cup, from a tap to a watering can, from the sky as rain, from a river to the sea. Why do you think that pour has any inherent sense of scale, big or small? The scale derives from the context, not from the pouring.

Comment: The definition in vocabulary.com is *wrong* so find a better resource. It is quite the opposite of a small, controlled flow.

Comment: I agree with the above: vocabulary.com is not a reputable dictionary site. They probably found a free word list of uncertain accuracy or provenance and stuck it on their website. You need to learn which dictionaries are trustworthy: seeing which ones are commonly cited in answers here is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pour forth is to pour out what one has. To bring forth is to bring out front, to display, to be seen. To pour forth is an expression meaning to offer in an unrestricted way, as by pouring out from a container. When one starts pouring there is little control or moderation. The last definition I have never heard. That might be to sprinkle or splash a bit. Hardly pouring forth.

The idea in the story is that once one has decided to admit to or offer their opinion or guilt the flood is upon you and all their thoughts and fears are spread before you. This is pouring forth their feelings.